# Finding a Constant for Euclidean Distances in Vector Set to Ensure Half Remain After Anomaly Removal

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, statistics, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I'm working on a method to remove anomalies from a set of time series. My goal is to ensure that at least $\lceil N/2 \rceil$ time series remain after the anomaly removal process, without having to explicitly check this condition each time. That leads me to this question:

Let ${x_1, x_2, ..., x_N}$ be a set of $N$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define $d_i = \sum_{j=1}^{N} ||x_i - x_j||^2_2$ for each $i \in {1, 2, ..., N}$.

Is there a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the number of $d_i$ that satisfy $d_i \le c \cdot$$\min_{i=1}^{N} d_i$ is always greater than or equal to $\lceil N/2 \rceil$?

(Here, $||x_i - x_j||_2$ denotes the Euclidean distance between vectors $x_i$ and $x_j$.)

I'm really stumped on where to begin with this problem. Any pointers on how to tackle it or suggestions for a solution would be a huge help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the random variable $X$ defined by $\Pr(X=x_i)=1/N$  and consider $m=E(X).$ Then $d_i/N=E(\|X-m\|^2)+ \|x_i-m\|^2.$ Since with this level of generality $\|x_i-m\|^2$ can be small, your question is almost equivalent to 'Can we find a number $c$ such that
$$\Pr(E(\|X-m\|^2)+ \|X-m\|^2\leq cE(\|X-m\|^2))\leq 1/2$$ or
$$\Pr\left(\frac{\|X-m\|^2}{E(\|X-m\|^2)}>c-1\right)\geq 1/2$$ which looks like the Markov inequality $\Pr(\frac{Y}{E(Y)}>y)\leq \frac{1}{y}$ which is in the opposite direction. For this reason, I do not believe that the result that you are looking for could be true without further hypothesis.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the very interesting response! I think I am able to follow most of your argument, but I am having some difficulty understanding why you've specified that Pr(E(∥X−m∥²)+∥X−m∥² ≤ c*E(∥X−m∥²)) should be less than or equal to 1/2. Could you please elaborate more on that part? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it seems that I misunderstood and you are asking for a $c$ such that the $\Pr (Y/E(Y)\leq c-1)$ is LARGER that 1/2. In this cas from Markov inequality the answer to your problem is $c=3$. Apologies.

Comment: Ok Great, thank you! If no one identifies any errors, I'll consider this problem solved! Excellent solution :)!